# GitHub Vernacular

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github

I noticed some issues on Rails were marked as closed via commits.  Does this mean that someone with commit privileges has committed a fix?  Why is this not marked as a merge? Because the person actually has a checkout of the master branch?

Thanks

**Edit**

Example:

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/4277

You'll notice `tenderlove` has committed 55cc16f.  Why is that a commit and not a pull?

Comment: Do you have a link one of the commits in question?

Comment: @larsmans - Updated the question with an example.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All this means is that a commit has been pushed to Github with a commit message indicating it closes the issue.

It doesn't necessarily mean that that commit has been merged into the repository's main branch, but you can certainly click through to the commit to get hold of the code that was marked as fixing the issue.